# how to perform crud operation on a given array in Javascript in a proper manner

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am given an assignment where I have to perform crud operations with Javascript array. well, I am not expecting the whole code I will just put down the things I am trying and getting problems within, now I have to achieve the following:
**1. fill the data from form fields values on form submit

2. get data into an html table

3. each row in table row must have edit and delete button

4. on clicking delete button the current row from the table should be deleted along with the array element

5. on clicking edit button the current row data should appear in the respected form field and again on submitting the data should get replace the current array element.**
this is my code:

```
//main array to store and get data from form
    let formData = [];

    //get form
    let form = document.getElementById('main-form');
    
    //get table body
    let tableBody = document.querySelector('#data-table > tbody');

    //initialize delete and update button
    let btnUpdate = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-edit">Edit</button>';
    let btnDelete = '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-dlt">Delete</button>';

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //storing form fields values as array to formData array as multidimensional array
        formData.push([
            btnUpdate,
            btnDelete,
            document.getElementById('name').value,
            document.getElementById('location').value,
            document.getElementById('age').value,
            document.getElementById('qualification').value,
            document.mainForm.gender.value,
            document.getElementById('address').value.trim()
        ]);

        //get data from array and show in table
        //outer loop iterates rows
        for (let row = 0; row < formData.length; row++) {
            let tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
            //inner loop iterates over cells
            for (let cell = 0; cell < formData[row].length; cell++) {
                let tableCell = document.createElement('td');
                tableCell.innerHTML = formData[row][cell];
                tableRow.append(tableCell);
                
            }
            tableBody.appendChild(tableRow);

        }
```

with this, I am able to get the data from the array and show it in the table, but the rows are repeating i guess because of the for loop its getting all the rows from the array everytime on form submit.
any help if why the rows are repeating in the table on form submit. i am only stuck at this problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/@etiennerouzeaud/a-simple-crud-application-with-javascript-ebc82f688c59

I hope this article will answer all your questions .

https://github.com/CodAffection/Pure-JavaScript-CRUD-Operations-with-Html